# Grouping Similar Annotation Semantically

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, semantic-segmentation

I have a TSV file that is the output of the Semantic-Segment-Anything model. In the model, the detection of objects may have different annotations. For instance, I am detecting my objects based on their X and Y coordinates. In my table, there is a column with results such as “building,” “a building,” and “a tall building.” However, I want to analyze the data in a way that considers all of these variations of “building” to be the same, so that my analysis will have more meaningful output. However, I don’t know what kind of annotation output Semantic-Segment-Anything would create to be clear that it targets those strings. Good to know that "building" is not just my case and this string variation happening to all annotations, actually this is the tricky part of the question which make it a bit complicated.
I want to know what the easiest way is to consider all of these variables of close output as one class.

| Frame Number | Class Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | building |
| 1 | a building |
| 2 | building |
| 3 | a tall building |
| 4 | a large building |
| 5 | building |
| 6 | a building |
| 7 | a building |
| 8 | building |
| 9 | tall building |
| 10 | a building |
| 11 | building |

I have seen some solutions that use dice coefficients or fuzzy string matching, but I want to know if there is a more semantic way of doing this.

Comment: so you have a dirty dataset and you need to clean it up?

Comment: Yes, I think it is the simpler expression of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to find a sub string ('building') within a given string (e.g a tall building, a large building). You can use regexp for such searching.

```
import re
#re.I for case insensitive search
re.search('building', 'a large buildinG', re.I)
```

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, "building" is just an example. I have different datasets and each of them has about 12000 rows of annotations. I have no clue about the range of different objects in these annotations.

Comment: You can do word count across the dataset. Find words that are used frequently. Based on top 5 words based on usage, you can group them. Please refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-k-frequent-words-data-set-python/

Note  : This crude method will also count frequently used words like "The", "a", "an" etc. and you may need to discard such words based on the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to know the answer. I find the solution in "nltk".  nltk as The Natural Language Toolkit library proposes various options for removing stop words, tokenizing, and Lemmatizing, which is ideal for my dataset. I tried many solutions such as fuzzy, counting and labeling characters, and dictionaries, but since my dataset is about 110k rows of data, I cannot process and know all the variations of the annotations and use mentioned methods.

```
#importing
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import pandas as pd

#dl additional resource and models
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('stopwords')


def preprocess_label(label):
    # If the label is N/A, return it unchanged (I had missing values which I wanted to keep)
    if pd.isna(label):
        return label

    # First of all, Lowercase all labels
    label = label.lower()

    # Second, Tokenize all label
    words = word_tokenize(label)

    # Removing stop words, I keep "it" according to my dataset nature
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    stop_words.remove('it')
    words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]

    # preparing Part-of-speech tagging for separating adjectives(JJ)
    tagged_words = pos_tag(words)

    # After that I Lemmatize the words to merge plural and singular forms
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word, pos in tagged_words if pos.startswith('NN') or word == 'it']

    # If there are multiple words, join them with a space
    return ' '.join(words)

# Load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('my_tsv_file_directory.tsv', sep='\t')

# Apply the function to the "my column" column
df['Class Name'] = df['Class Name'].apply(preprocess_label)
    
# Save the modified DataFrame to a new TSV file
df.to_csv('output_tsv_file.tsv', sep='\t', index=False)
```